# How do I use jsdoc with factory functions?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

So I have a module that exports a factory function. The factory function takes in settings and returns a lib bound over that settings object. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to document this with jsdocs; I've been playing with namespaces, typedefs, and `memberof` until my head is spinning. No matter what I do, it's just not listing the functions as part of the library definition. Help?

I can get them to show up as global functions if I remove the memberof entirely, but nothing I've tried so far makes them show up as member functions

Sample code:

```
/**
 * @namespace ServerControl
 */
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Library
 */

/**
 * Factory function that constructs a lib
 * @param {*} settings Settings for constructing a lib
 * @param {*} rancher The rancher library to be used by the lib
 * @returns {ServerControl~Library} The lib
 */
module.exports = function(settings, rancher) {
    return {
        /**
         * Evacuate a host
         * @memberof {...ServerControl~Library}
         * @method evacuate
         * @param {String} name The name of the host to evacuate
         * @returns {Promise} A promise that fulfills when the evacuation is done
         */
        evacuate: name => {
            const server = settings.servers.filter(item => item.display === name)[0];
            return rancher.evacuateHost(server.host, server.env);
        }
        // [more methods snipped]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem that my modules always expose factory functions or maps of functions. I always use a `@typedef` outside the module wrapper. This way I get code completion in IDEA *and* can generate nice HTML docs.

[Here the generated documentation](http://playground.yalst.de/temp/Generated/index.html) for this example:

```js
/** @namespace SharedLib */

/**
 * @typedef SharedLib.PriorityQueueFactory
 * @function
 * @template T
 * @param {function(T, T): Boolean} comparator Comparison function like for <code>Array.prototype.sort</code>
 * @return {{pop: function(Array<T>): Array<Array<T>| T>, push: function(Array<T>, T): Array<T>}} an object containing the functions to manage the queue
 */

// UMD wrapper - sorry!
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
    }
    else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = factory();
    }
    else {
        root.returnExports = factory();
    }
}(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this,
    function () {

        /** @type {SharedLib.PriorityQueueFactory} */
        function priorityQueueFactory(comparator) {
            // ...
    return priorityQueueFactory;
}));
```